# Reading .csv file from file upload control gives File not found exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

I am trying to upload .csv file to SQL database, as per my code below when I am trying to read .csv file by assigning the File PATH to a variable my program runs fine, but when I am retrieving the same PATH from File Upload control I am getting File Not Found Exception.
Can anyone please guide me how to get ride off this error. Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
using System.IO;

public partial class Exercise1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fupPath.HasFile)
        {
            string csv_file_path = @"C:\TechnicalTest\GskTest\Csv\SampleData.csv";
            //string csv_file_path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/File"), fupPath.FileName);

            DataTable csvData = GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(csv_file_path);
            Response.Write("Rows count:" + csvData.Rows.Count);

        }
    }

    private static DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(string csv_file_path)
        {
            DataTable csvData = new DataTable();
            try
            {
              using(TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path))
                 {
                    csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
                    csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
                    string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
                    foreach (string column in colFields)
                    {
                        DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
                        datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
                        csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
                    }
                    while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
                    {
                        string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
                        //Making empty value as null
                        for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (fieldData[i] == "")
                            {
                                fieldData[i] = null;
                            }
                        }
                        csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return csvData;
        }

    //protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //{
    //    if(fupPath.HasFile)
    //    {
    //        //string csv_file_path = @"C:\TechnicalTest\GskTest\Csv\SampleData.csv";
    //        String csv_file_path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/File"), fupPath.FileName);
    //        fupPath.SaveAs(csv_file_path);
    //        //string path = Server.MapPath("~/")
    //        //String csv_file_path = Server.MapPath(fupPath.FileName).ToString();
    //        //csv_file_path = csv_file_path.Replace(@"\\","\"");

    //        DataTable csvData = GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(csv_file_path);
    //        Response.Write("Rows count:" + csvData.Rows.Count);

    //    }
    //}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to save the file first

```
if (fupPath.HasFile)
{
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(fupPath.FileName);
    String csv_file_path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/File"), filename);
    fupPath.SaveAs(csv_file_path);
```

and then read it

```
DataTable csvData = GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(csv_file_path);
```

In your commented Code `Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/File"), fupPath.FileName);` will not work because `fupPath.FileName` contains the Full path.

Comment: If I am using fupPath.SaveAs(csv_file_path); I get DirectoryNotFound Exception was unhanded by user code error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a file which is present in your local system.You need to save the file first in required location and then you have to read that file by using that location .

Solution:`fupPath.SaveAs(csv_file_path);`

i.e;

```
     if (fupPath.HasFile)
       {

        string csv_file_path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/File"),fupPath.FileName);
       fupPath.SaveAs(csv_file_path);
        DataTable csvData = GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(csv_file_path);
        Response.Write("Rows count:" + csvData.Rows.Count);

       }
```

****Reason:****In order to read file,first we have to know the location of the file.file upload control doesn't give file location(Because of security problems).By using file upload control we can save file in our required location.Then by using that location we can read file.If you don't want to save file.After reading file you can delete that file.

Comment: If I am using fupPath.SaveAs(csv_file_path); I get DirectoryNotFound Exception was unhanded by user code error

Comment: Do you create "File" folder?.else create it.Right click on website path(present in soln explorer and create folder with name "File")